# Why yum's download speed is too slow

Tags: fedora, yum, repository

My yum download speed in fedora is in average less than 5KB/s and goes to less than 1KB/s but my normal download speed is around 140KB/s. I tried installing `yum-fastestmirrors` but didn't help.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've installed [Yum Fast Downloader plugin](http://hedayatvk.wordpress.com/2011/05/11/introducing-yum-fast-downloader-plugin/) and the download speed is now good.

Answer (score 11):

At the end of the day `yum` is just a glorfied http downloader, so you can determine the actual URL that it's using to download a package and attempt to do the same using `curl` or `wget` and see if the slowness is being induced by the mirror site or something else local to your system.

You can use the `repoquery` to see the URL of one of the RPM packages like so:

```
$ repoquery --location kernel
http://kdeforge2.unl.edu/mirrors/fedora-archive/fedora/linux/updates/14/x86_64/kernel-2.6.35.14-106.fc14.x86_64.rpm
```

So you could use `curl` to analyze the download like so:

```
$ curl -O http://kdeforge2.unl.edu/mirrors/fedora-archive/fedora/linux/updates/14/x86_64/kernel-2.6.35.14-106.fc14.x86_64.rpm
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 21.9M  100 21.9M    0     0  2717k      0  0:00:08  0:00:08 --:--:-- 3054k
```

#### fastestmirror

Yum makes use of plugins to enhance it's features. One of these plugins is called [fastestmirror](http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/YumUtils/Plugins/Fastestmirror). Sometimes this plugin can be the cause of slowness. The mirror sites that this plugin selects can sometimes not be the best ones to use all the time.

You can remove the preferred list of mirrors from this plugin by deleting this file:

```
$ sudo rm /var/cache/yum/timedhosts.txt
```

Also you can temporarily disable the `fastestmirror` plugin with this command:

```
$ sudo yum --disableplugin=fastestmirror install <package>
```

Comment: I tried that and my speed is again low. It seems that the mirror is the problem but I've installed fastestmirror plugin for yum. what should I do now?

Comment: @Farzam - see updates regarding fastestmirror

Comment: @sim I didn't understand what you mean.

Comment: @Farzam - see my updates regarding the fastestmirror plugin. Let me know if you still don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you get anything near the latest yum, it will now download from multiple urls at once ... and has drpm downloads/regeneration built in.

Older releases have rebuilds from the latest in rawhide here:

http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/james/yum-rawhide/

...or you can rebuild that locally, if you can't use anything from there.

Comment: I'm using Fedora 19